# Is there any reason not to make all my components a single class?

Tags: c#, entity-system

What would be the downside to using a generic all-encompassing `Component` class versus specific classes (`PositionComponent`, `InputComponent`, et cetera) for each component in an entity/component system?

By 'generic' I mean:

```
class Component {
  String name; // component name, like "position"
  Map<Key, Object> attribs; // Attributes like "x" and "y" stored here.  
}
```

Where a 'specific' component might be:

```
class PositionComponent {
  int x, y;
}
```

I feel like creating a separate class for each component means tons of 3-5 line classes in my code-base.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6719162/165500) over on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things to watch out for in the "generic" component approach you propose:

- It means that a component is pure data, and cannot have any behavior unless you start doing things like allowing behavior objects (function pointers, or what-have-you) to be stored in the `attribs` member or in a similar member. This is a valid possible approach for an ECS, but not all ECS's choose the "component is pure data" model, and it's certainly not the *only* approach.
- The generic component stores all attributes in a dictionary; this means string (or some kind of key) lookups to recover data, boxing, and non-contiguous storage. The associative container also has storage overhead. All of these have performance impacts. You are also abandoning type-safety.
- Storage of the name as a string (rather than being able to intuit it from the type of the component) also means extra overhead.

Personally, I've never seen a "generic component" like you proposed out in the wild for anything *real*. It seems like a terribly poor choice, if for no other reason than when you have generalized the component so much you might as well reduce the overhead by making the *entity* the thing that stores all those properties, and namespace them:

```
class Entity {
  Dictionary<string, object> components;
}

// ...

var entity = new Entity();
entity.components.Add("Position.X", 1.0f);
entity.components.Add("Position.Y", 2.0f);
entity.components.Add("Position.Z", 3.0f);
entity.components.Add("RigidBody.Mass", 100.0f);
entity.components.Add("Killable.HP", 15.0f);
```

(But I still don't recommend it.)

Comment: Also, consider the typos like "Killalbe.HP" the compiler won't catch - good luck finding those. To fix this every dictionary key should be created as static/const string and that brings us back to simply defining the variables in the interface in the first place.

Comment: I may misunderstand the ECS concept a bit, but isn't a component supposed to be pure data, with the systems operating on the components to define behaviors? Sorry, I guess I don't understand the benefit of an ECS if you're mixing your behavior with your data. Any sources on the web about that? :)

Comment: There is no single, universally-accepted definition of an ECS, and there are plenty of existing ECS implementations that allow components to have behavior. "ECS" is just a rough pattern to follow, flavors where components have and don't have behavior are both equally valid.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I did a pro/con list based on your answer and ultimately I came away with the class-based approach you advocated. Two major pros stuck out for me: computed properties, and self-documenting components. I'm accepting this answer.